# Multiple Keys in KeyBinding?

Tags: wpf, binding, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I want to setup hotkeys in my Wpf application.
Using KeyBindings works in the simple case, for example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, etc

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+B" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource localCusomCommands}, Path=AddTTRowCommand}" ></KeyBinding>

<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="B" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource localCusomCommands}, Path=AddTTRowCommand}" ></KeyBinding>
```

But if I need hotkeys with multiple keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, etc

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="P,B" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource localCusomCommands}, Path=AddTTRowCommand}" ></KeyBinding>
```

Don't work.

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+B+A" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource localCusomCommands}, Path=AddTTRowCommand}" ></KeyBinding>
```

Don't compile. `Error   15  Unrecognized ModifierKeys 'B'.`

How to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot bind to multiple key combinations like that, only multiple modifers and a (single) key. You'll have to dive in to a much lower level and handle the keyboard/input signals directly (or find a library that does this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i told, there is implementation for overriding the KeyBinding and Gestures for multiple keys. refer the below link. He has overriden the implemetation of InputGesture to achieve this multikeybinding. 
http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/multikeygesture

Comment: Modifed my answer, try it.

Comment: I tried this before.
If I type `Ctrl+C+B` it will fired; if I type `Ctrl+D+B` it will be fired again, if I type `Ctrl+B` it will be fired.

Comment: I think we may need to override the KeyBinding Class to accept mutiple keys.