# Advanced/Complex Shortcuts in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I want do define more advanced keyboard shortcuts like `Ctrl+^, Ctrl+M`.
I have seen them in Visual Studio 2015 and thought, they would be great for my own applications, but I couldn't find a way to define such keyboard shortcuts in WPF and C#. I only know how to define "normal" shortcuts like `Ctrl+S`:

```
InputGestures.Add( new KeyGesture( Key.S , ModifierKeys.Control ));
```

How can I create more advanced shortcuts like in Visual studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multi key gesture in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181991/multi-key-gesture-in-wpf)

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181991/multi-key-gesture-in-wpf  and that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483141/multiples-keys-in-keybinding .  It should answer your needs :)

Comment: I will try the code later and tell you if it worked

Comment: Depending on what you need, you may not have to do complex gestures like that. If one gesture does a certain event, like opening a menu item or another window, then you can just handle the gesture from the newly focused control.

Answer (score -1):

To create complicated shortcuts you should add some logic to your application.
Like handle "`Ctrl+^`" and then wait for "`Ctrl+M`".

I know nothing about some existing feature that would allow you to implement complicated shortcut sequences in one line of code.